# I'm having trouble converting time stamps to readable strings

Tags: python

Is there an easy alternative way to do this? I keep ending up with my else executing I don't know why. The debug prints return two different data types as well.

```py
    def last_played(player_id):
        response = requests.get(f'{base}player?id={player_id}')
        if response.status_code == 200:

            parsed = json.loads(response.text)

            last_connect_timestamp = parsed["last_connect_timestamp"]
            now = time.time()

            print(last_connect_timestamp)
            print(now)

            difference = last_connect_timestamp - now
            last_connect_timestamp /=  1000

            if difference > 86400:
                last_seen = "more than a day ago on " + str(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(last_connect_timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
            if difference > 18000:
                last_seen = "few hours ago " + str(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(last_connect_timestamp).strftime('at %H:%M'))
            if difference > 3600:
                last_seen = "more than a hour ago " + str(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(last_connect_timestamp).strftime('at %H:%M'))
            if difference > 600:
                last_seen = "few minutes ago " + str(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(last_connect_timestamp).strftime('at %H:%M'))
            if difference > 60:
                last_seen = "a minute ago"
            if difference < 59:
                last_seen = "few seconds ago"

            else:
                last_seen = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(last_connect_timestamp).strftime('on %Y-%m-%d at %H:%M')

        else:
            print(f"Web-driver  : Failed to retrive data from API! Error : {response.status_code}")
            last_seen = "Failed to retrive data!"

        return last_seen
```

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Also note: if difference is `> 86400` it's also `> 60`; consider what the ordering of your conditions will do in that case.

Comment: As msanford noticed, your `else` is only on the `if difference < 59`. So as long as it is `>= 60` you will get the `else`. You probably want to change all the `if`s to `elif`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You subtract greater datetime from smaller.

```
            difference = last_connect_timestamp - now
```

`now` is greater than `last_connect_timestamp`, therefore your difference will always be sub zero.

Another thing, use `if` and `elif`. Otherwise you will keep overwriting your variable.